# Counting the number of characters in comments line in C

Tags: c, counting

I need to count the characters in the comments from a C program, that is supplied as a standard input. This is my function, but for some reason it's not counting right. Can you help me please?

```
int characters(FILE *file)
{
     int i=0;
     char ch[500], *p;
     while (fgets(ch, sizeof(ch),file)!=NULL)
     {
        p=ch;
        while (*p)
        { 
           if (*p=='/')
           { 
              p++;
              if (*p=='*')
              {
                 p++;
                 while (*p!='*' && *(p++)!='/')
                 {
                    i++;
                    p++;
                 }
              }
           }
           else
              p++;

         }


   return i;
}
```

Comment: What happens if someone has something that looks like opening a comment in a string in the program? Or if a comment is opened, but never closed? What happens when '/' and '*' come from different fgets calls?

Comment: Excuse me but you didn't open the file I think ...

Comment: This code is difficult to understand and maintain. And, as Art says, there are special cases which it does not cover. I think a state machine is a better choice here, and I've put an answer to that effect below.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I think the problem is in the innermost loop:

```
while (*p!='*' && *(p++)!='/')
```

should be

```
while (*p!='*' && *(p+1)!='/')
```

But this will break if it sees something like this:

```
/* comment * */
```

because the first part of the condition `*p!='*'` will be false at the first asterisk, so you could do something like this instead:

```
while (!(*p=='*' && *(p+1)=='/')) {
   p++;
   i++;
}
```

Note: if the line is broken you will get a segmentation fault:

```
    /* comment * \n
    */
```

you still have to deal with that but you should add `*p` to the inner loop:

```
while (*p && !(*p=='*' && *(p+1)=='/')) {
   p++;
   i++;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

I suspect this is your problem:

```
while (*p!='*' && *(p++)!='/')
```

Remember that `p++` evaluates to the value of `p` *before* the increment; in effect, the test is

```
while (*p != '*' && *p != '/')
```

so if `*p` evaluates to `*`, the test will fail.  Change that to

```
while (*p != '*' && *(++p) != '/')
```

Answer (score 1):

Your code scared me.

There were a lot of pointers going on, and nested loops.

It's easy to get the logic wrong in there, and the code is difficult to extend if you need to make changes.

Might I suggest a different solution?

A [state machine](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Finite-state_machine)!

We'll read in the file one character at a time and keep track of what state the machine is in. We'll then use this to decide whether or not we are in a comment.

```
#include <cstdio>
#define S_CODE          1
#define S_ONESLASH      2
#define S_LINECOMMENT   3
#define S_BLOCKCOMMENT  4
#define S_BLOCKSTAR     5

int characters(FILE *file){
    int ccount=0;
    char ch;
    int state=S_CODE;
     while ((ch=fgetc(file))!=EOF){
        switch(state){
            case S_CODE:
                if (ch=='/')
                    state=S_ONESLASH;
                break;

            case S_ONESLASH:
                if (ch=='/')
                    state=S_LINECOMMENT;
                else if (ch=='*')
                    state=S_BLOCKCOMMENT;
                else
                    state=S_CODE;
                break;

            case S_LINECOMMENT:
                if (ch=='\n')
                    state=S_CODE;
                else
                    ccount++;
                break;

            case S_BLOCKCOMMENT:
                if (ch=='*')
                    state=S_BLOCKSTAR;
                ccount++;
                break;

            case S_BLOCKSTAR:
                if (ch=='/')
                    state=S_CODE;
                else if (ch=='*')
                    state=S_BLOCKSTAR;
                else
                    state=S_CODE;
                ccount++;
                break;
        }
    }
    return ccount;
}

int main(int argc, char **argv){
    FILE *fin=fopen(argv[1],"r");
    printf("%d\n",characters(fin));
}
```

Notice how we use the characters `/` and `*` and `\n` to mark transitions between the machine's different states and how in some states we increment the comment-character counter, but in others not. I think it's much easier to keep track of what's going on here.

Answer (score 0):

The problem, as already stated, is in line `while (*p!='*' && *(p++)!='/')` 
in this case, the second part of statement ( `*(p++)!='/'` ) is evaluated only if first part "fires", hence `p`is incremented if an asterisk is found.

Answer (score 0):

it seems working

```
int characters(FILE *file)
{
    int i = 0;
    char ch[500], *p;
    fread(ch, sizeof(char), 500, file);
    p = ch;
    while (*p)
    {
        if (*p=='/' && *(p+1) == '*')
        { 
            while (*p && (*p != '*' && *(p+1) != '/')) 
                ++p;
            ++i;
        }
        ++p;
    }
    return i;
}
```